Unable to install bismark
Trying to install bismark using the following command
conda install bioconda::bismark

The package is listed here: https://anaconda.org/bioconda/bismark
The following is displayed as I executed the above code in WSL/Ubuntu
Channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: |
warning  libmamba Problem type not implemented SOLVER_RULE_STRICT_REPO_PRIORITY
warning  libmamba Problem type not implemented
SOLVER_RULE_STRICT_REPO_PRIORITY # this appears like a 100 times
warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
failed
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from 
current channels:
  - bioconda::bismark
Current channels:
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda
  - defaults
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda
To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package 
you're looking for, navigate to
  https://anaconda.org
and use the search bar at the top of the page.   

I expected to install bismark like I would do for any other bioconda repos, like fastp, Trimmomatic, etc. Bismark is listed and I typed exactly as I did according to https://anaconda.org/bioconda/bismark. However I got a PackagesNotFoundError.
